# Why react doesnt show anything on web page? Reactjs and vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

When I want to edit react js I find an oddity here. First, why doesn't the kiuu page appear, what? The two codes I wrote should be correct and I didn't see any errors ranging from tags, return statements, imports. Is there an explanation in this case? This is my first time using react js.

main.jsx

```
import { React } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import navSection from "./components/nav/navSection.jsx";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <navSection />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

index.css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

navSection.jsx

```
import './navbar.css';

const navbarSection = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default navbarSection;
```

navbar.css. i try to give color into my text, but same result nothing like on this page.

```
p {
  color: black;
}
```

[image]

Comment: React components should be named as `NavSection` not `navSection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official doc](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#hook-names-always-start-with-use)

> React component **names** *must start with a capital letter, like
> StatusBar and SaveButton*. React components also need to return
> something that React knows how to display, like a piece of JSX.

So in your example file navSection.jsx should be like below(See how I wrote component class naming):

```
import './navbar.css';

const NavbarSection = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavbarSection;
```

Now...

```
import { React } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import NavSection from "./components/nav/navSection.jsx";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <NavSection />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Gosh, my Java habits have carried over. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.